# Does the Pressure Point mod improve jump attacks?

Tags: warframe

The [Pressure Point](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Pressure_Point) mod improves the damage of some melee attacks; it definitely improves normal attacks and the spin attack (attacking from slide), and definitely does *not* improve charge attacks.

Does it improve any of the following?

- ground finisher (the downward stab into knocked down foes); supposedly this is based on charged damage?
- jump attack
- aerial spin attack (sprint+jump -> crouch -> melee)

I ask because I'm really enjoying the heavy AOE electric damage of Amphis' jump attack and would like to beef it up to more reliably 1-hit Shockwave MOAs.

Comment: i dont think pressure point works at all tbh its bugged and needs fixing at least on ps4 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote from the wiki:
`This mod affects regular (non-charged) damage only`

So I believe it really does increase absolutely everything except the standard charge attack. At the moment I'm spinning and sliding around with my Dual Ethers and find this mod is a must have for any melee weapons you don't intend to use charge attacks with.

I definitely noticed an increase in damage for the ground finisher and the jump attack with my Fragor, as it's easier to tell with a hard-hitting, slower weapon.
The aerial spin attack is also affected by this mod.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear. Have you done any definite tests, seeing how much damage you do with & without the mod to enemies of a given type in the same level? The jump AOE attack is particularly hard to test, since its damage is also (as far as I can tell) reduced based on how far enemies are from the impact point.

Comment: I've just done some quick testing with my fragor in the same level, with and without a fully maxed pressure point.